NodeMCU is unable to connect with WebSocket endpoints of a server configured over AWS EC2 and Nginx
I'm trying to connect my NodeMCU, send data to our server (project built using NodeJS, deployed on AWS EC2 with Nginx), and connect through WebSocket endpoints. The same endpoints work fine when tested from a ReactJS client or Postman Desktop agent.
I tried following from the server end, but nothing worked:

Nginx -> sites-available -> default file -> updated reverse proxy and trusted_proxies values to local IP.


Removed SSL certbot from primary domain, and tested on http:// site.


Used public IPV4 of EC2 instance.


Used different headers for websocket connection in request body of NodeMCU code.


Changed port numbers from 80, 8000, 443 but no avail.

Would love to get support from the community, as I've been stuck on this for the past 3 days and already behind the deadline. Let me know if any additional details are required.
Looking forward to positive responses and lots of learning!
Facing the following issue from the NodeMCU side, logged-from serial monitor,


Connected to server

this is response
HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols

response ends
Server: nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)

Date: Fri, 16 Aug 2024 10:36:04 GMT

Connection: upgrade

Upgrade: websocket

Sec-WebSocket-Accept: <websocketKey>

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Connection: close

Content-type: text/html

Content-Length: 28

Unsupported protocol version
WebSocket handshake successful



Not sure which part is causing "Bad Request" and "Unsupported Protocol version" issues.

Following is the code from NodeMCU,


void setup() {

Serial.begin(115200);

WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

Serial.print("Connecting to WiFi");

while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {

delay(500);

Serial.print(".");

}

Serial.println("");

Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

// Optionally set the insecure mode if the server does not have a valid certificate

client.setInsecure(); // Use this only if you cannot validate the server's SSL certificate

if (!client.connect(host, port)) {

Serial.println("Connection failed");

return;

}

Serial.println("Connected to server");

//Perform WebSocket handshake

String request = "GET /socket.io/?transport=websocket HTTP/1.1\r\n";

request += "Host: " + String(host) + "\r\n";

request += "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";

request += "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";

request += "Sec-WebSocket-Key: " + generateWebSocketKey() + "\r\n";

request += "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n";

request += "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits=15\r\n";

request += "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n"; // Added header

request += "\r\n";

client.print(request);

// Wait for server response

while (client.connected()) {

if (client.available()) {

String response = client.readStringUntil('\n'); // Read until newline character

Serial.print("this is response");

Serial.println(response);

Serial.print("response ends");

// Print the full response for debugging

while (client.available()) {

Serial.write(client.read());

}

// Check for the WebSocket upgrade response

if (response.indexOf("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols") != -1) {

Serial.println("WebSocket handshake successful");

sendWebSocketMessage(fingerprint);

break;

}

}

}

}

void loop() {

// Wait for a response

while (client.available()) {

String response = client.readStringUntil('\n'); // Read until newline character

Serial.println(response);

}

delay(1000);

}

void sendWebSocketMessage(const String &message) {

byte messageLength = message.length();

byte frame[2 + messageLength];

frame[0] = 0x81; // Text frame

frame[1] = messageLength; // Payload length

message.getBytes(frame + 2, messageLength);

client.write(frame, sizeof(frame));

}

String generateWebSocketKey() {

// Generate 16 bytes of random data

byte key[16];

for (int i = 0; i < 16; ++i) {

key[i] = random(0, 256); // Generate random byte

}

// Base64 encode the random data

String keyBase64 = base64::encode(key, 16);

return keyBase64;

}



